# Local API Calls Interspire

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

I have Interspire(email marketing) installed on my server. API calls can be sent to a php file that handles xml requests. I am using curl to send the request and it looks like this

```
$ch = curl_init($this->api_endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$result = @curl_exec($ch);
return $result;
```

$this->api_endpoint is a url that points to the php file that handles the xml request. 
I am trying to make the whole thing work faster and I thought if I didn't have to sent the request out to the internet and back maybe I could save some time, but I am not sure if it is possible to send the request "locally"... I'd like to possibly have $this->api_endpoint equivalent to ../../xml.php I have actually tried this, but it doesn't work. Can an API call be handled within a server and not need to be sent out to the internet to work?